# Hide titlebar in a particular activity in tab group android

Tags: android, titlebar

I have a tabhost with multiple tab activities.For one particular activity I need to hide the default title.is it possible?Even if I use  requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE) the tabhosts title overrides it.Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

to particular activity to remove titlebar.

Comment: this doesn't work...Tabhost title bar overrides it as I have said in the question